# Limit VirtualBox guest upload speed (but not download speed) on Windows host

Tags: windows, networking, virtualbox

I want to limit the network upload speed of a VirtualBox virtual machine, but leave the download speed unrestricted. This must be accomplished by the (Windows) host, the guest OS has no network speed limiting options. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure network bandwidth limiter with VBoxManage.

> Limits are configured through VBoxManage. The following example creates a bandwidth group named Limit, sets the limit to 20 Mbps and assigns the group to the first and second adapters of the VM:
>
> ```
> VBoxManage bandwidthctl "VM name" add Limit --type network --limit 20m
> VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --nicbandwidthgroup1 Limit
> VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --nicbandwidthgroup2 Limit
> ```

As specified on: http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bandwidth_limit

And answered in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311413/virtual-box-limit-bandwith-on-network